# Non repeating elements from array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, random

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); //initialize the random seed

    while (true) {
        const char arrayNum[4] = { '1', '3', '7', '9' };
        int RandIndex = rand() % 4; //generates a random number between 0 and 3
        cout << arrayNum[RandIndex];
    }
}
```

When generating this numbers some of them are repeating and i don't want this.Is a way for this?

Comment: well... you cant have an infinite loop that keeps printing different numbers when you pick only out of 4. What do you really want?

Comment: Note that eliminating repeats makes your sequence less random, not more random.

Comment: Let s propose i have a for with 10 repeats

Comment: i don t want the numbers repeat

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want to avoid consecutive numbers from repeating, or if you want every number in the entire sequence to be unique.

Comment: I want every number in the entire sequence to be unique

Comment: Please don't use `srand`/`rand`. Use the facilities in the `<random>` header for much higher quality random numbers (and btw; `time(NULL);` is a *horrible* seed).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bool array that indicated if the index has been used or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); //initialize the random seed
    const char arrayNum[4] = { '1', '3', '7', '9' };
    bool taken[4] = { false };
    int RandIndex;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        do{
             RandIndex = rand() % 4;
        }while(taken[RandIndex]);
        taken[RandIndex] = true;
        cout << arrayNum[RandIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but it takes(on average) more and more work for each subsequent number. And the use of magic numbers makes it prone to errors.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I agree

Comment: this works men thank u